# How to Execute second MySQL CONDITION if first one fails (PHP/MySQLi)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need help. I know that I can use "if...elseif" in PHP but the problem is the current condition is already inside a long "elseif" so I don't want it to be nested by creating another "if..." inside it.

I have my search form (please see image below) and my mysqli statement that works fine for one side only (Price to).
I want to be able to : when a user select a "category" like "Coach", and enter one of the price (from & to), the search must work normally as expected. 
if the user only enter "price from", the statement work from the inputted amount, and if he enters "price to" the statement also work to the inputted amount.

I tried to use many operators (OR / AND...) but still not achieving what I want.

```
elseif ($category=="coach"){
echo "3 !!!!!!!" ."<br>";
$result = $connection->query("select * 
                            from tblcoach 
                            where price>='$pricefrom' 
                            and price<='$priceto'");
}
```

Below is my sql statement that only work when I 
and I want to

[image: image of web form]

Comment: I think you are going to have to build the WHERE clause dynamically in a variable. Show more code from above the piece you showed

Comment: this is the code : elseif ($category=="asia")
$result = $connection->query("select * from tblasia where price>='$pricefrom' and price<='$priceto'");

elseif ($category=="australia")
$result = $connection->query("select * from tblaustralia where price>='$pricefrom' and price<='$priceto'");

elseif ($category=="coach"){
echo "3 !!!!!!!" ."<br>";
$result = $connection->query("select * from tblcoach where price>='$pricefrom' and price<='$priceto'
                              UNION
                              select * from tblcoach where price<='$priceto' or price>='$pricefrom'");

Comment: Can you read code **in a comment** I cannot. Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43093173/edit) link under the question and post that code so we can read it

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to add an "or input is null" clause to your `WHERE` clause.  Logically it might look something like this:

```
select * 
from tblcoach 
where (price >= ? or ? is null)
  and (price <= ? or ? is null)
```

Then you'd bind the first two parameters to your "price from" value and the second two parameters to your "price to" value.

Hint: This is a good time to start using query parameters and prepared statements.  It will make this, and other things, easier.  You *can* do the same thing with your current potentially-SQL-injectable code, probably comparing with an empty string or default value instead of `null`.  But the idea is the same.  The logic is essentially to use the value for comparison if it exists or perform no meaningful comparison if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks David. I wrote this ($result = $connection->query("select * 
                               from tblcoach
                               where (price>= '$pricefrom' or '$pricefrom' is null)
                                 and (price<= '$priceto' or '$priceto' is null)");) and the result is : it's only work fine for "Price to".  If I input "Price from" I got nothing on the screen. I don't why !!!

Comment: @J.Doe: By "nothing on the screen" do you mean a completely blank page?  Sounds like there's a PHP error.  Check the PHP logs, turn on error reporting, etc.  Also, since you're still using string concatenation/interpolation to build your SQL queries, you need to also check what the *actual* query is at runtime that you're executing.  The variable names tell us nothing about what the variables contain.

Comment: sorry not to be explicit. No, I got no result from the query statement if I input the "price from". I only have exact result if I input a number on "price to". It's not a blank page but I get no results.  By the way, they way I added parameters is right?

Comment: @J.Doe: Well, the "right" way to add parameters is to use actual query parameters and not directly injecting string values like this.  But if you insist on doing it this way, that's fine at least for the scope of this one question.  (Though using query parameters will *probably* make this easier.)  As for the query itself, if you're not getting the results you expect then, again, you need to *at least* check what the query *actually is*.  I can't see inside your computer, I don't know what your code is doing when it runs.

Comment: so what do you need as code? and what part of code do you need? Here's the code 
elseif ($category=="coach"){
echo "3 !!!!!!!" ."<br>";
/*$result = $connection->query("select * from tblcoach where price>='$pricefrom' and price<='$priceto'
                              UNION
                              select * from tblcoach where price<='$priceto' or price>='$pricefrom'");*/   My table is consist of 3 columns (ID, price, location). that's all

Comment: @J.Doe: I don't really know how else to ask this again.  You're dynamically building SQL code to execute based on the values of the `$pricefrom` and `$priceto` variables.  So you currently *don't know* what the *actual* SQL query is.  You need to *find out*.  Even if it's as simple as echo-ing that SQL statement to the page.  If your SQL code isn't finding the results you expect, then you need to *look at the SQL code you're executing*.  Then test it by manually executing that *same code* on your database and seeing if any results are found.

Comment: Thanks. I've just used the nested "if...elseif" inside "if...else" and solved the problem.